# Удвоение в слове "желанный"

Tags: удвоенные-буквы

Почему слово "желанный" пишется с удвоенным "н"? Есть же правило, относящееся до суффиксов ан, ян. Или это правило касается прилагательных, образованных от существительных?

Comment: «Относящееся до суффиксов ан, ян»? Достали до суффиксов.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Привёл один из примеров традиционного употребления предлога.

Comment: http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EE%F2%ED%EE%F1%E8%F2%F1%FF+%E4%EE

Comment: Когда ж это было... Можно ещё вспомнить — «сапоги относились».

Comment: Читаешь вот так литературу, классическую, несовременную, осознаешь красоту слога, регистрируешь в памяти различные сочетания, обороты, начинаешь их употреблять - и натыкаешься на современные традиции. Как же быть? В этом смысле литература прошлых столетий вредна, она мешает правильному усвоению норм.

Comment: А Вы читаете старую литературу только для правильного усвоения норм? Язык-то меняется. Вы же владеете современными нормами? А старые нормы мы можем использовать для воспроизведения старой эпохи - для стилизации.

Answer (score 1):

Слово "желанный" является отглагольным прилагательным, образованный от глагола "желать" (что делать?) - несовершенный вид. По правилам русского языка, это прилагательное надо бы писать с одной буквой "н", но оно является исключением из правил.

Поэтому, сверившись с орфографическим словарем, пишем правильно - желанный, так же, как и нежданный, нечаянный...

*Это был желанный гость и хозяева с радостью приняли его у себя дома.*

Comment: _Юлия Казакова: Это был желанный гость и хозяева с радостью приняли его у себя дома._ === Предложение сложносочинённое, перед союзом "и" нужна запятая.

Comment: Ответьте, пожалуйста, на последний вопрос